# How do I read files as a object or is there a better solution to this? Please see code bellow for context

Tags: java, file

So in my java class, we need to read this file and somehow converts its content into an object

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;

public class Calendar {

  public Appointment[] appointments;

  Calendar()
  {
    appointments = null;

  }
  Calendar(int capacity, String filename)
  {

    Appointment[] appointments = new Appointment[capacity]; 
     //you can see that appointments is an Appointment object
    readCalendarFromFile(filename);}

   private void readCalendarFromFile(String fileName){

    Scanner fileRead = null;

    try

    {

      fileRead = new Scanner(new FileInputStream("appointments.txt"));

for(int r = 0; r < 30; r++)

        appointments[r]= fileRead.nextLine(); ----> This is where I am getting my error from as I cannot convert String into an object. Is there a way that I can pass this
      fileRead.close();
    }
    catch (FileNotFoundException fe)
    {
      fe.printStackTrace();
      System.err.println("Unable to open the file " + fileName + " for reading.");
    }
  }

}
```

Is there any way that I can convert filetext into an object or do I have to do something else with it? I have to make an appointment an object so I can't change it into anything else sadly.

Comment: Java is to Javascript as Pain is to Painting, or Ham is to Hamster. They are completely different. It is highly recommended that aspiring coders try to learn the name of the language they're attempting to write code in. When you post a question, please tag it appropriately - this lets those with knowledge of the language you need help with to see your question.

Answer (score 0):

You have to have a class Appointment somewhere, and what you are trying to do is add an object of the type Appointment to the array appointments, based on the info you get from the text file, right?

So, you have your for loop that reads every line from the text file, and then you need to create instances of Appointment for each line.

The class Appointment has some kind of constructor, that you need to call to create a new object (read: "a new instance") from it.

Let's assume it looks like this:

```
public Appointment(String title, String time, String location) {
    this.title = title;
    this.time = time;
    this.location = location;
}
```

Let's also assume that every line in the file `appointments.txt` is formatted in the following way:

```
<Title>, <Time>, <Location>
```

Which means, that you would have to parse the line that you read from the file by splitting it (the delimiter in this case would be the ",". Just do a quick research on the internet on how to split Strings in Java, it's pretty easy actually.

When you have all the bits of information in separate variables, you have to call the constructor of Appointment, to create a new appointment that you can then add to your array. Assuming that you have three Strings with the title, the time and the location of the appointment (or whatever info you have in the text file), this would look like this:

```
try{
    fileRead = new Scanner(new FileInputStream("appointments.txt"));

    int counter = 0;
    while(fileRead.hasNext()) {
        String lineRead = fileRead.nextLine();
        // here comes the parsing of the line into three String variables
        appointments[counter] = new Appointment(title, time, location);
        fileRead.close();
    }
} catch(FileNotFoundException ex) {
    // Do some exception handling in here, or just print the stacktrace
}
```

The line I want you to pay the most attention to is the Line, where it says `new Appointment(title, time, location)`. The difference between this and the code that you posted is, that here I create a new object of the type Appointment, that corresponds with the type of the array you created earlier, in the line `Appointment[] appointments = new Appointment[capacity]`.

You tried to directly add a String to the array, although you declared an array of the type `Appointment`, not of the type `String`.

You should read up on the topic of objects in Java in general, and what constructors are, what they do and how you use them.

For example, this topic gets explained really well and exhaustive in [the official Java tutorials from Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/constructors.html) (the company that develops the Java Language). I linked you the specific section that talks about constructors, but I would suggest that you read at least the whole chapter and everything before it that helps you understand what they actually talk about.

Hope this helps :)

Comment: It is just that I need to extract the title, time and location from the text

Comment: "Which means, that you would have to parse the line that you read from the file by splitting it (the delimiter in this case would be the ",". Just do a quick research on the internet on how to split Strings in Java, it's pretty easy actually."